# Understanding Euler's Totient Rule in RSA

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography, totient-function

I'm trying to understand the use of Euler's Totient Theorem in RSA. It is defined as : if $a$ is coprime with $n$ then $$ a^{\phi(n)}\equiv{1 modn} $$
I am unable to understand how the above implies that for any integers $m$ and $k$ the following statement holds : 
$$m^{k*mod\phi(n)}\equiv m^{k}mod n $$

Comment: If $x=q\phi(n)+k$, then $m^x=m^{q\phi(n)+k}=(m^{\phi(n)})^qm^k\equiv1^qm^k=m^k$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner for your proof you will also need the assumption that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, otherwise you will need CRT to make good of the claim.

Comment: good point, @AnuragA